# Private variable inner class: explanation of value?

Tags: java, oop, private, inner-classes

Curious as to why for the following code

```
public class OuterClass{
  int i;
  public void printme(){
     System.out.println("Outerclass");
     i+=20;
     System.out.println(i);
       class InnerClass extends OuterClass {
          public void printme(){
              System.out.println("InnerClass");
              i+=10;
              System.out.println(i);
           }
        }

        InnerClass second = new InnerClass();
        second.printme();    
        System.out.println("Outerclass-2");
        System.out.println(i); 

        return;
     }

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("start");
        OuterClass first = new OuterClass();
        first.printme();

     }


}
```

The output is

> start Outerclass 20 InnerClass 10 Outerclass-2 20

But if int i is declared private the output is

> start Outerclass 20 InnerClass 30 Outerclass-2 30

Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the field has no access modifier, it has default visibility.

From the scope of `InnerClass#printme()`, a sub class' method, it is accessible. So

```
i+=10;
```

is accessing the `InnerClass` instance's field, which was initialized to 0.

`private` fields are not visible to sub classes, so `InnerClass` can't access its own. But because your `InnerClass` is an inner class which is within the body of the `OuterClass` it can access the enclosing instance's field. So

```
i+=10;
```

is accessing the `OuterClass` instance's field.

Comment: if you give me your address, I will send you a slower keyboard.  You always seem to beat me with answers like this.

Comment: @DavidWallace I live across the street from Stackoverflow's servers.

Answer (score 3):

A `private` field cannot be accessed in a `sub-class` but is can be accessed in an inner class.

So if you have

```
int i;

// in InnerClass extends Outerclass
i += 10; // access the parent of this InnerClass
```

however

```
private int i;

// in InnerClass extends Outerclass
i += 10; // access the OuterClass as the parent is not accessible.
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  If it's not private, then its inherited by `InnerClass` - that is, the `i` that's operated on is the one in the `InnerClass` object.  If it is private, it can't be inherited, so the `i` that's operated on is the one in the containing object.

Answer (score 1):

`InnerClass` is not strict inner class, which is commonly known from declarations in class body. In this case it is [local class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) and is indeed a kind of inner class, but quite different rules are applied. This problem is all about inheritance and consequently - shadowing variables.

In your case, if you extend class with `default` (none) modifier you can access this field and effectively you can see superclass's field.

If field is declared as `private`, then subclass cannot see it, but it has its own as it extends your `OutterClass` so the new object starts with default value of 0.

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#shadowing-and-local-classes) at the documentation's part about `Shadowing and local classes`

Comment: Technically, it _is_ an inner class. That's why it can access the field of the enclosing instance. [All local classes are inner classes (§8.1.3).](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)